# Apply audio tags from CSV file

Tags: sound, automation, tag

I have an archive of audio files named like `<title>.<ext>` (e.g. `Track title.ogg`) and a CSV file with metadata for those files with the following structure:

```
Album,Track number,Title,Author,Cover file,Foo,
Lorem ipsum,1,Dolor sit amet,John Doe,image.png,bar
...
```

Is there a way to automatically apply the metadata to the corresponding tracks?

Please also consider the following.

1. Some file names contain possibly problematic charachters like spaces, `'`, `.`, `,`. I could remove them easily via regex, but I'd prefer to avoid that if possible because it would mean that I also have to rename those files manually after applying the tags.
2. I'd much prefer to use only FOSS software.
3. The metadata includes the name of the cover for each file. I would like to add it automatically too, but I could also do that manually (the tracks are divided in several groups - roughly for author - sharing the same cover, so doing that manually shouldn't require much time).

Either CLI or GUI solutions are good as long as they work.

Comment: There are some programs, depending on the tagging used. `midv2` only works in id3v2 tags (e.g. mp3-files). `mp3tag` (https://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html) is GUI driven, but should allow batch processing (did not try) and supports lots of different tag formats. Only Windows version, never tried with `wine`. Another one is `kid3` (https://sourceforge.net/projects/kid3/), also available for Linux. `ffmpeg` is able to write tags to files, but afaik only if you create new files (or copy some). See https://blog.1a23.com/2020/03/16/read-and-write-tags-of-music-files-with-ffmpeg/ (did not try myself).

Comment: And for the special characters: When using CLI, just put them in quotes when passing to the command.